# How to copy a plot using copyobj

Tags: matlab, copy

I have script that calls a function in Matlab.

The function creates a figure.

I wanted 2 figures, one that is produced by the function.

The second figure that is the exact copy of that figure produced by the function.

I do not want to rerun the function to obtain the figure.

Here is my code so far:

```
new_handle=copyobj(2,figure(2));
```

I tried to use the child and parent commands too but kept getting errors and the script would not run.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with [`copyobj`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/copyobj.html). You only need a handle to the old axis and a handle to the new figure:

```
plot(1:8,randn(1,8)) %// example plot
a = gca; %// get handle to axis

f = figure; %// new figure
copyobj(a,f) %// copy axis and its children to new figure
```